# Space appearing on firefox, but not chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

folks.

Today,I decided to install firefox and test my navigation bar out on firefox instead of google chrome. Firefox shows a random space ontop while chrome doesn't. Anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

This is what firefox looks like compare to chrome.(Sorry for the bad quality, I resized it bad.)

[image]

If it matters, this is the code i'm using:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Blitz</title>

<style>
body{
margin: 0px;
padding:0px;
}

.Blitz{
background-color:#2DDEDE;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
border-color:black;
}

.Navigationbar{
height:40px;
width:500px;
background:#a7e8ee;
border:none;
}


.Navigationbar li{
display:inline;

}


.Navigationbar a{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>


<div class="Blitz">
<h1><center>Blitz</center></h1>
<ul>
<div class="Navigationbar">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Featured</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="information">
<!--Information about the site here. Pictures to go with that-->

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/)? All browsers have different default margin/padding/etc.

Comment: The HTML and CSS actually looks alright, the only thing I can think of is that maybe Firefox is reading the whitespace between the opening body tag and the opening Blitz div tag. Does it help if you take out those carriage returns?
Furthermore, swap the opening 'ul' tag with your 'div.Navigationbar' tag, it's not properly nested.

Comment: @Eraph This isn't actually a whitespace problem - please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is occurring because the margin-top of your header is poking out of the top of your div, and is not just due to newlines or whitespace in your HTML.

To prevent the margin of your header element from sticking out of the top of your div and affecting positioning, use `overflow: auto;` on your `.Blitz` element.

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9676k73g/

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the newlines on your navigation so that it's all in one line in your HTML. It might look messy, but I have discovered in the past that an annoying space will render in some browsers just because the HTML is nicely formatted.